# TypeScript generate function

Tags: node.js, typescript, code-generation

I'm developing a tool to generate some boilerplate code for me.

The idea is to parse all the .json files located in a folder named config and generate interfaces for each of them and some auxiliar functions as well.

Generating the interfaces was easy with the help of the `quicktype` package.

Now my idea was to generate another file/class that was utility functions to handle the generated interfaces that in this case would be nothing more than a `get{InterfaceName}()` that would return a object of the InterfaceType with all the data that was loaded from the .json files.

I'm not a pro in typescript but in the Java world I guess I could use reflection to achieve this.

Any input on how to do this is really appreciated or even if it's possible at all.

test.json

```
{
    "key" : "value"
}
```

test.d.ts

```
export interface TestConfig {
    key: string;
}
```

utils.ts

```
function getTestConfig() {
    // Load json file, etc
    return {
        key: jsonData.key
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you only need to read the json and give it the correct interface? Lets break it down:

#### Loading json files

To load the .json file you'll need nodejs's [fs package](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). It's advised to use the [promises variation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) for convenience.

#### Converting the json string to an object

There's a built in class for that in javascript:

```
JSON.parse(jsonFileStringFromPreviousStep);
```

#### Asserting the interface

[Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion) is a way to let typescript know that a variable is of certain type/interface. Since you've built the interfaces from the files via `quicktype` it should be a safe to assert interfaces onto parsed objects.

```
function getTestConfig(): TestConfig {
    const jsonString = ;// Load json file
    const testObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    
    return testObject as TestConfig;
}
```

#### Generating file with getObjectConfig methods

You'll have to get a [list of json files](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) in the directory you want to use for your configs. Then it should be a simple string templating solution. You'll have to handle style conventions(PascalCase/camelCase, etc.), but that should be trivial.

```
const importLines: string[] = [];
const functions: string[] = [];
const files = ...; // get list of files via fs.readDir
for (const filename of files) {
  importLines.push(`import ${filename} from '.....pathToInterfaces/${filename}.d.ts';`);
  functions.push(
    `function get${filename}Config(): ${filename}Config {
    const jsonString = ...; // Load json file
    const ${filename}Object = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    return ${filename}Object as ${filename}Config;
  }`);
}
const imports = importLines.join('\n');
const body = functions.join('\n\n');
const result = `${imports}\n\n${body}`;
// Write result to file
```